# How can I change the link format in will_paginate for page_cache in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, will-paginate

I want to use page_cache with will_paginate.

There are good information on this page below.

http://railsenvy.com/2007/2/28/rails-caching-tutorial#pagination
http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/02/05/episode-5-advanced-page-caching

I wrote routes.rb looks like:

```
map.connect '/products/page/:page', :controller => 'products', :action => 'index'
```

But, links of url are not changed to '/products/page/:page' which are in will_paginate helper.
They are still 'products?page=2'

How can i change url format is in will_paginate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is that route declared *above* any RESTful resources routes? That is, your route file should look like the following:

```
map.connnect '/products/page/:page', :controller => 'products', :action => 'index'
map.resources :products, :except => [:index]
```

If your routes look correct, you could try monkey-patching the way `will_paginate` generates the page links. It does so in `WillPaginate::ViewHelpers#url_for(page)`. It's some fairly complex logic in order to handle some tricky edge cases, but you could write a new version that tried the simple version for your `product`s first:

```
# in lib/cache_paginated_projects.rb
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.class_eval do
  old_url_for = method(:url_for)
  define_method(:url_for) do |page|
    if @template.params[:controller].to_s == 'products' && @template.params[:action].to_s == 'index'
      @template.url_for :page => page
    else
      old_url_for.bind(self).call(page)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
app/helpers/custom_link_renderer.rb

class CustomLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::LinkRenderer
  def page_link(page, text, attributes = {})
    @template.link_to text, "#{@template.url_for(@url_params)}/page/#{page}", attributes
  end
end
```

add this line to `config/environment.rb` file

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:renderer] = 'CustomLinkRenderer'
```

Answer (score 1):

A little addition to the current answers, I had to spend hours to figure it out.

If you have some more complex routes, like for example including filtering in my case, **make sure that the "higher level" routes come first** (and not just that they are above the RESTful one), otherwise will_paginate picks up the first usable one and sticks the extra params at the end of the URL in a non-pretty way.

So in my case I ended up with this:

```
map.connect "wallpapers/:filter/page/:page", :controller => "wallpapers", :action => "index", :requirements => {:page => /\d+/, :filter => /(popular|featured)/ }
map.connect "wallpapers/page/:page", :controller => "wallpapers", :action => "index", :requirements => {:page => /\d+/ }
map.resources :wallpapers
```

So now I get pretty URLs like: *wallpapers/popular/page/2* instead of *wallpapers/page/2?filter=popular*

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
map.products_with_pages "/products/page/:page", :controller => "products", :action => "index"
```

You can even do it with a has_many ie: products has_many :items

```
map.resources :products do |product|
  map.items_with_pages "/products/:id/page/:page", :controller => "products", :action => "show"
end
```

Then your controller could look like

```
def show
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @items = product.items.paginate :per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]
end
```

Which would give you a url like: http://domain.com/products/123/page/3 where 123 is the product id and 3 is the page id. You could also use permalinks and have the 123 id changed to a more seo friendly word.